# VBS to SFTP WinSCP

Tags: jscript, wsh

I am trying to put log files into a SFTP Server. When I try to run I get error Line 1 Char 28 Syntax error. Anyone have any Idea to different code they got working for VBS? Looking for something simple.

`cscript Transfer.vbs  /type:winscp /SourceFolder:PATH TO LOG DIR /FTPType:sftp /FTPSite: SFTPSITE:PORT  /FTPUser:USER /FTPPass:PASS`

```
<job>
<reference object="WinSCP.Session" />  
<script language="JScript">  

try
{
// Setup session options
var sessionOptions = WScript.CreateObject("WinSCP.SessionOptions");
sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol_Sftp;
sessionOptions.HostName = "SFTP";
sessionOptions.UserName = "USER";
sessionOptions.Password = "PASS";

var session = WScript.CreateObject("WinSCP.Session");

try
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload files
    var transferOptions = WScript.CreateObject("WinSCP.TransferOptions");
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode_Binary;

    var transferResult = session.PutFiles("c:\\Users\PATH TO LOGS\\*", "/", false, transferOptions);

    // Throw on any error
    transferResult.Check();

    // Print results
    for (var enumerator = new Enumerator(transferResult.Transfers); !enumerator.atEnd(); enumerator.moveNext())
    {
        WScript.Echo("Upload of " + enumerator.item().FileName + " succeeded");
    }
}
finally
{
    // Disconnect, clean up
    session.Dispose();
}
}
catch (e)
{
WScript.Echo("Error: " + e.message);
WScript.Quit(1);
}

</script>
</job>`
```

Comment: People here can't tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't show it.

Comment: My code is what is listed above.. I am very new to VBS...

Comment: No, your code is `Transfer.vbs`. You've only showed us how you're executing it.

Comment: Posted code so you could see it.. File name is Transfer.vbs

Comment: You have [wsf code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/15x4407c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), not plain VBScript code.

Comment: How could I make it work on a windows 7 machine? OR what is my next step? But thank you for adding the tag.. Also renamed file Transfer.wsf

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to install the SDK for Windows machine. Register the .dll file that winscp gives you. Also register via Com as well. Thakn you for looking into it